# How to store big zipped XMLs and efficiently extract only its some specific data (Alfresco)?

Tags: java, xml, alfresco, stax

Compression can radically reduce a big XML file size, that has impact to:

- storage space usage, IO Waits (reads and writes)
- network usage

I have to extract only some specific data from zipped XML.
This is Rhino's JavaScript (mostly Java) example:

```
var zis = new java.util.zip.ZipInputStream(document.properties.content.getInputStream());
var ze = zis.getNextEntry();
if (ze!=null){
    var scanner = new java.util.Scanner(zis,"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A");
    var content = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
    var docXml = new XML(content);
    logger.log("xml mytag/text(): "+docXml.mytag);
}
zis.closeEntry();
zis.close();
```

But, there is no need to load the full XML to DOM if I have to extract only some specific elements (from XML header for example). The algorithm should stop to read the XML file when all requested items will be found (or there is no chance to find them).

Is there any provided Alfresco's service or java library that does it and  extracts requested items from XML using e.g. [StAX2 API](https://github.com/FasterXML/stax2-api) ([Woodstox](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox))?

Comment: Doesn't seem easy. Can you tell us how you'd specify what is to retreive ? It could be e.g. the first non root tag, the 300th <whatever> tag, all <whatever> text content... There may be ways to do it as fast as possible if we know that.

Comment: @GPI - for example the map (hashmap) of paths

Comment: You can use Stax2/Woodstox to extract the XML-parts you need and then run the XPaths. It is not easy to do though (lots of devils in the details). I found an old [blog](http://andreas.haufler.info/2012/01/conveniently-processing-large-xml-files.html) explaining the technique and the related source code has moved around but appears to be maintained [here](https://github.com/scireum/sirius-kernel/tree/master/src/main/java/sirius/kernel/xml). I have not used it but it might be just enough for what you need.

Comment: @vanOekel thanks, I going to check these links and let you know of the results

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pretty well use Stax for this:

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLEventReader r = factory.createXMLEventReader
                   (ze.getName(),zis );
```

and then read XMLEvent by XMLEvent using the XMLEventReader.
If you have found the relevant tag and value in the XML which you are looking for, you can call r.close(), which will Close the Stax Parser (but not the zip Input stream) and proceed with the next zip entry.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to use StAX:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108090/how-to-get-xml-element-path-using-stax-stax2